# In MATLAB, how do you calculate the variance around a vector?

Tags: matlab, vector, variance, eigenvector

I have a matrix of eigenvectors and I'm interested in finding a vector of variances of the data (X) around each eigenvector (U).

Thanks

Comment: Please give a definition of 'the variance around a vector'. In general the info on how to calculate the variance can be found via `doc var`, you may also be interested in `doc cov`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the eigenvetors and eigenvalues from the matrix `A` with `[V,D] = eig(A)`, you have the variance of the data for each eigenvector in the diagonal elements of `D`, namely `diag(D)`.

Comment: Great! I don't think I worded my question very well, but your reply was exactly what I was looking for. So the eigenvalue is the variance of A "around" the eigenvector?

Comment: I think the question is clear if you know about the topic ;)